# SSRS 2008: Clear report contents when new parameter value is chosen

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an internal SSRS report that can be run against data for different clients.  The report has just one parameter "Client" which is a drop-down menu populated by a DataSet which populates from essentially "select distinct Client from ClientStuff" which returns a short list of clients.

The user chooses a Client from the drop-down and hits View Report, report populates with data. Fine. But then, when user chooses a different client, the report contents remain up and showing until "View Report" button is hit.

So here is the question: How do we force report contents to **clear out** when a new value is chosen for the parameter? Too often, user selects a new client but forgets to hit View Report, thus looking at one client name but seeing data as another. I want a blank screen showing as soon as the user picks a new value for the parameter.

I've searched and searched on this problem, I've set parameter properties to "Always Refresh", I've deleted and re-deployed reports... nothing seems to make it happen.

Comment: the parameter value should be visible somewhere on the report, otherwise people come to you with a printout and you don't know what it is. that's an issue you need to address anyways. and then to your question i don't think it's possible. You can try to set an AutoRefresh but that will only be a partial fix.

Comment: Thanks, @busytools.  You are absolutely right, so we've added the parameter value into the report itself, and although not ideal, it helps a lot.  I also marked the first answer below as The Answer as it says essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter properties options to "Always refresh", etc. have to do with cached data, not whether the report will refresh once a new value is selected (which I assumed was the case, too). Unfortunately, according to a few sources I've found ([Such as this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/c12f965b-7e58-4481-bf6e-64b03b82b17c/refresh-ssrs-report-on-selection-of-dropdown-parameter)) indicate that refreshing the full  report when changing a parameter value is not possible without user input (i.e. pressing the Apply button/the Enter key).

What I generally do is find somewhere on the report to display the parameter value that's currently chosen, so end-users will see what the report is displaying. Not nearly as good a solution, but that's what I've been stuck with.

Comment: Thanks, @jeffrey-van-laethem.  I marked this as the accepted answer.  Displaying the parameter value on the report helps a lot, I don't know how we didn't think of that before!  Not the solution we wanted from SSRS, but much better than nothing.  It's good to know from your helpful answer that we're not missing something obvious.